# How to call an imported function in the template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Consider the following code that makes use of a method and an imported function:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{sayHello()}}
    {{sayDate()}}
    {{DateTime.now()}}
  <div>
</template>

<script>
import {DateTime} from "luxon"

export default {
  methods: {
   sayHello() {
    return "hello"
   },
   sayDate() {
    return DateTime.now()
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

- `sayHello()` works fine because it is defined in `methods`.
- `sayDate()` is fine as well.
- `DateTime.now()` in `<template>` fails with `[Vue warn]: Property or method "DateTime" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

**How should I call `DateTime` so that it is correctly addressed in `<template>`?**

Comment: Only properties exposed via the Component or Vue are available inside the template, not other global nor imported functions.

Comment: @deceze: thanks - this settles it. Would you mind making this an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Boussadjra's recommendations, but if you really want to `DateTime.now()` in your template, you can import `DateTime` as data.  Here is a similar example that I built.

ImportObjectToData.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="import-object-to-data">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <span>{{ DataObject.getMessage() }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import DataObject from './data-object.js'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        DataObject
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

data-object.js

```
const DataObject = {
  message: 'Hello from DataObject',
  getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}

export default DataObject;
```

Comment: Ah this is excellent,  thanks! I just tried that in my code (adding `DateTime` to `data()` and using it directly) and it works great. The advantage is that I am not creating a one line function that does the conversion only once, but do it directly in the template.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use methods for rendering purposes, instead of that you could use computed properties, for example in your case you could do :

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{sayHello}}
    {{now}}
  <div>
</template>

<script>
import {DateTime} from "luxon"

export default {
  computed:{
    sayHello() {
       return "hello"
    },
   now(){
      return DateTime.now()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Note that the computed properties are called without using `()`

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful information (and I agree with you), the question however is about how to directly call a module function in the template.

Comment: you're welcome, any external stuff to be shown in template  should be passed by component instance properties/methods

Comment: if the  module contains functions that need to be handled by an event from the template you could spread them inside the `methods` option

Comment: note that the methods are used event handlers inside the template not to render something